# UINavigationBar is not working with customize UIColor?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uicolor

Navigation bar is behaving well with the following code:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor().CGColor
```

But when I am trying to implement the same thing with a RGB color, it's not working:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 81, green: 139, blue: 91, alpha: 1).CGColor
```

seems to me strange, isn't it? Any reason why?

Comment: try dividing by 255 and add 0x before it => 0x81/255

Comment: thanks you SamuelD

Comment: http://www.codingexplorer.com/create-uicolor-swift/ => you can create an extension, so you can create a color more easily

Comment: Yes, it's a good practice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it will work. Because RGB value range 0 to 1.

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 81/255, green: 139/255, blue: 91/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
```

Comment: I think, you didn't understand my problem. I ask for having problem with customized RGB UIColor. I am not having problem with this  **UIColor.brownColor()**

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add .0 also to get the exact colour
Try this solution....

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 81.0/255, green: 139.0/255, blue: 91.0/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
```

Answer (score 0):

More appropriate is:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 81/255, green: 139/255, blue: 91/255, alpha: 1)
```

actually what I am in need. :)